Wrong key, Right key script in lua
I'm doing a prank ransomware program using AutoPlay Media Studio and the only script I did was this:
Dialog.Message("A message from ElsaWare...","WRONG CODE! Didn't you pay to me?")

Now, what I'm planning to do is a script that goes like this: In the input box, once you put the correct code, you'll get a message like "That's the right code! Now your videos will be recovered.". But if you add the incorrect code, you'll get the message that I've written above.
